# How to calculate number of unique response codes in an apache server log file?

Tags: linux, apache, logfile, http-response-codes

I just started a system admin job. I was given a log file which contains some response codes (actually they are too many). I need to make a list of the codes use, for example, 400, 200, 304, 404. Then, I need to show how many times each response code is repeated. For this last task, I did this:

```
less file name | grep -c "404"
```

But still I need to make a list of those response code.

This is a sample of the log file:

```
10.229.120.3|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:58:40 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1143|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.4|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:58:53 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|2367|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.3|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:58:55 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1194|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.4|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:08 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|2212|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.3|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:10 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1780|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.4|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:23 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1268|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.3|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:25 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1160|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.4|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:38 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1206|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.3|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:40 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1138|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.4|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:53 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1304|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.3|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:59:55 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|2476|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

Comment: Without seeing the logs, we can only guess.

Comment: This is a general question that applies to any log file with HTTP response codes. The log file is huge and cannot be shared here. This is just a sample, but I need to find out the response codes used in the whole file.  10.229.120.4|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:45:38 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|2197|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
10.229.120.3|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:45:55 -0500]|/keepalive.html||200|10|1806|HTTP/1.1|GET|TLSv1.2|AES256-GCM-SHA384
169.204.192.216|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:45:59 -0500]|/NASApp/clcs/Action/SubmitPlan||302|-|77570|HTTP/1.1|POST|-|-
169.204.192.216|-|[12/Apr/2020:23:45:59

Comment: There's no general way how to detect response codes. The format of the log file is important and we don't know it. Are the codes presented in brackets, double quotes, after/before a specific keyword, etc.? If you just grep for `404`, you might match a date string (20200**404**) or whatever else.

Comment: Please include the log sample into the original question, it's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Just updated the original question to include the log sample. The codes come in this format |200|, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' '{ a[$6]++} END{ for (i in a) print i "\t" a[i] }' logfile | sort -n
```

This counts the number of occurrences of the sixth field and prints status code and occurrences for each array element. The output is then sorted numerically by status code.

Use `sort -nrk2` if you want the output sorted by occurrence in `r`everse order.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! This is a bash script, right?

Comment: It's [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) with `sort`, but you can put it in a bash script if you like.